# Django how to authenticate credentials via a desktop application

Tags: python, django, authentication

I am new to django and web dev in general (reference for my skill level) and I want to be able to authenticate a users credentials via a desktop application.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Either desktop application or web there won't be any difference in Django server or your authentication request. You can send username and password in post request (web and desktop both) and it will log you in to application if credentials are correct.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is it possible to provide an example post request or a template so I can fully understand. Thanks.

Comment: refer this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial04/